# Search through a dataframe for a partial string match and put the rows into a new dataframe with only their IDs

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of publications that have the following rows:

publication_ID , title, author_name, date
   12344, Design style, Jake Kreath, 20071208
   12334, Power of Why, Samantha Finn, 20150704

I ask the user for a string and use that string to search through the titles.

**The goal:** Search through the dataframe to see if the title contains the word the user provides and return the rows in a new dataframe with just the title and publication_ID.

This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

 publications = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep= "|")

 search_term = input('Enter the term you are looking for: ')
 def stringDataFrame(publications, title, regex):
      newdf = pd.DataFrame()
      for idx, search_term in publications['title'].iteritems():
        if re.search(regex, search_term):
        newdf = concat([publications[publications['title'] == search_term], newdf], ignore_index=True)

        return newdf
print(newdf.stringDataFrame)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Yeah I just did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `.str.contains` and `.loc`

```
publications.loc[publications.title.str.contains(search_term), ['title', 'publication_ID']]
```

Just be careful, because if your title is `'nightlife'` and someone searches for `'night'` this will return a match. If that's not your desired behavior then you may need `.str.split` instead.

---

As jpp points out, `str.contains` is case sensitive. One simple fix is to just ensure everything is lowercase.

```
title_mask = publications.title.str.lower().str.contains(search_term.lower())
pmids = publications.loc[title_mask, ['title', 'publication_ID']]
```

now `Lord`, `LoRD`, `lord` and all other permutations will return a valid match, and your original `DataFrame` has the capitalization unchanged.

Comment: Worth mentioning `sr.contains` is case sensitive by default and can incorporate regex. If word boundaries / punctuation is an issue, OP should probably use a specialist library.

Comment: Would I need to use a function then?

Comment: @Py.rookie89 no need for a function using this method

Comment: so is this how I would save this in a dataframe                                       
pmids= pd.DataFrame(publications.loc[publications.title.str.contains(search_term),
                                     ['title', 'publication_ID']])

Comment: no need for the DataFrame constructor. When you slice a DataFrame this way, it returns a DataFrame, so simply assign it to another variable if you need: `pmids = publications.loc[...]`

Answer (score 1):

Full example but you should accept the answer above by @ALollz

```
import pandas as pd
# you publications dataframe
publications = pd.DataFrame({'title':['The Odyssey','The Canterbury Tales','Inferno','The Lord of The Rings', 'Lord of The Flies'],'publication_ID':[1,2,3,4,5]})

search_term = input('Enter the term you are looking for: ')

publications[['title','publication_ID']][publications['title'].str.contains(search_term)]


Enter the term you are looking for: Lord

       title               publication_ID
3   The Lord of The Rings      4
4   Lord of The Flies          5
```

per your error you can filter out all `np.nan` values by as part of the logic using the new code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

publications = pd.DataFrame({'title':['The Odyssey','The Canterbury Tales','Inferno','The Lord of The Rings', 'Lord of The Flies',np.nan],'publication_ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

search_term = input('Enter the term you are looking for: ')

publications[['title','publication_ID']][publications['title'].str.contains(search_term) & ~publications['title'].isna()]

Enter the term you are looking for: Lord

    title                 publication_ID
3   The Lord of The Rings       4
4   Lord of The Flies           5
```

Comment: I am getting this error:                                                                               
 ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: @Py.rookie89 you have `np.nan` values in the title column is my guess you can filter these out or make them blank strings